# Why child input field is wider than parent div

Tags: css

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <input class="field" type="text">
    <textarea class="field" row="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{width:300px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px;}
.field{display:block;width:100%;margin:10px 0;padding:10px;}
```

I expect width of text input and textarea should be exactly equal to parent div. but they are not . can anybody explain why?

[Live code](http://jsfiddle.net/aLz6b/1/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The total width is calculated as a sum of `padding` + `width` + `borderWidth`. This is the default behaviour of the box model. You can change it by using `box-sizing` property. In your case:

```
.field {
    ...
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aLz6b/3/

Further reading: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 3):

Its because you have `padding` applied to the `.field` remove padding and see it will work.

```
.field{display:block;width:100%;margin:10px 0;}
```

**OR**

you have `100%` width set so just set width as below.

```
.field {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 280px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `width: 100%` property applies to the content box, not the border box.  If you are using CSS3 you can set `box-sizing: border-box` to obtain the expected size.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.wrap{width:300px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 0px;}
```